# Qu'est-ce que le « home de neige » ?

Tags: sens, anglais, emprunts, belgique

On attribue à [Madame de Staël](https://fr.wikipedia.org/wiki/Germaine_de_Sta%C3%ABl) l'emploi (l'emprunt) de [*home*](http://www.cnrtl.fr/definition/home) ([o:m], masc.) pour « chez nous », emploi qui n'a pas survécu :

> Si vous interrogez des Anglais voguant sur un vaisseau à l'extrémité
>   du monde, et que vous leur demandiez où ils vont, ils vous répondront
>   : *home*  (chez nous), si c'est en Angleterre qu'ils retournent. Leurs
>   vœux, leurs sentiments, à quelque distance qu'ils soient de leur
>   patrie, sont toujours tournés vers elle.
>
> [ Madame de Staël, [*Corinne, ou l'Italie*](http://gallica.bnf.fr/ark:/12148/bpt6k877130k/f245.item), éd. Garnier fr., 1807,
>   p.223 ]

Ensuite pendant la plus claire partie du 19<sup>e</sup>, c'est utilisé au sens plus restreint de [domicile](http://larousse.fr/dictionnaires/francais/home/40204?q=home#40119), « dans son caractère personnel et familier » (TLFi : « Mais au moins pour les jours de consultation du docteur vous devriez avoir un petit home, avec vos fleurs, vos livres, les choses que vous aimez », Proust, 1918) et pour parler des intérieurs anglais puis français « avec une pointe de snobisme » (DHLF/Rey). Puis en 1895 on atteste le sens d'« établissement où l'on accueille certaines catégories de personnes » (TLFi), essentiellement le *foyer* et le *centre d'accueil*, et ce serait courant en français de Belgique et du Luxembourg avec l'idée de *local de réunion* (DHLF/Rey). Et c'est dans ce contexte qu'on semble donner le syntagme *home de neige* au TLFi.

---

- Qu'est-ce que le *home de neige* : un foyer, un local, une résidence
  secondaire, un lieu de détention ; destiné à des soins de santé, de
  villégiature, pour les enfants ; en montagne, en neige/glace, pendant/pour
  l'hiver ; y a-t-il un *home des neiges* de sens différent ; est-ce toujours courant ?
- [ Dans *Corinne*, c'est comme si en fait l'auteure rapportait un
  propos et on a les italiques puis on l'explique ou on
  lui attribue un sens entre parenthèses ; a-t-on un exemple du début
  du 19<sup>e</sup> d'emploi de *home* qui serait plus « autonome » que celui-là, et dans le sens en question (*chez nous*) ? ]

Comment: En France le *home de neige* semble inconnu. Centre d’accueil pour vacanciers à la neige ?

Comment: @Laure Merci. Quand vous dites ça, le _à la neige_ s'applique aux vacanciers ou au centre ? Je ne reconnais pas la syntaxe... c'est comme _à la mer_ ? Mais le lieu de la neige c'est quoi, les Alpes ?? Je viens tout juste d'apprendre le sens de _centre d'accueil_ pour le centre/kiosque d'interprétation à l'entrée d'un parc (pour moi le centre d'accueil c'est surtout par référence au centre privé conventionné i.e. personnes âgés/mineurs). Sinon j'ai trouvé _classe de neige_ (je connais sans la préposition, _classe-neige_, qui n'existe pas sous cette forme). C'est intrigant !

Comment: Des vacances à la neige pour moi - française de l'hexagone - ce sont des vacances à la montagne en hiver et ça sous entend en général la pratique des sports d'hiver. Je suppose que les  Québécois ont en rapport différent à la neige qui fait plus partie de leur environnement quotidien.  On peut dire par exemple « je ne suis jamais allé à la neige ».

Comment: La « classe de neige » c'est [tout un concept](https://fr.wikipedia.org/wiki/Classe_de_neige) en France, ça fait partie des « [classes de découvertes](http://www.education.gouv.fr/bo/2005/2/MENE0402921C.htm) », de la même façon il y a les « classes vertes » et les « classes de mer ».

Comment: Home des neiges ? Pas si abominable...

Comment: [Home  de neige](http://www.famillebonnier.fr/piwigo/index.php?/category/42) en contexte illustré, mais probablement employé avec humour par quelqu'un ayant aussi lu la définition du TLF. Quant à ceux qui disent que le mot n'est plus utilisé de nos jours, ils ne connaissent pas les homes d'enfants, nom que porte encore de nos jours certains établissements pour enfants, l'emploi du mot « home » apporte une touche plus familialle et / ou sociale que « centre » ou « maison ». Il en va de même pour les « home pour personnes âgées ». Plus employé il me semble en Suisse francophone qu'en France.

Comment: @Laure également très utilisé en Belgique [francophone](https://www.ggno.be/?Liste-des-homes-et-maisons-de-repos-de-Bruxelles) et [néerlandophone](http://www.homevogelzang.be/) pour désigner une maison de retraite ou de repos. Ce qui ne fait pas avancer la question d'origine qui reste bien mystérieuse.

Answer (score 8):

Il semble que la solution pourrait bien nous arriver des [mots croisés](https://mots-croises.tazzaz.com/definition/home-de-neige.html), pour lesquels un *home de neige* est simplement un domicile fait de neige, un **igloo** (aussi **iglou** selon *le Petit Robert*), cette pittoresque demeure hivernale conçue par les inuits.

Comment: Mais oui bien sûr... Ceci dit ça colle mal avec la définition de home dans du TLF cité par le PO.« Établissement où l'on accueille certaines catégories de personnes. Home d'enfants, home d'accueil pour les personnes âgées, home de neige ». Ton explication irait plus avec  « Foyer domestique, domicile » du même TLF, non ?

Comment: J'admets que vous avez un bon point. Je laisserai tout de même ma réponse pour l'instant, en attendant que quelqu'un en propose une meilleure. Elle me semble au moins plausible, si pas entièrement satisfaisante au vu de votre observation.

Comment: Tout à fait plausible et la seule réponse valable à cette heure pour quiconque a pris la peine de lire la question avant d'y répondre.

Comment: Pour me faire l'avocat du diable, je pourrais dire que l'iglou étant une demeure saisonnière, à reconstruire entièrement l'hiver suivant, on pourrait le considérer comme un abri temporaire destiné à recevoir une famille. Les inuits savaient d'ailleurs le construire en quelques heures, et ne devaient donc pas forcément y retourner s'ils s'en éloignaient trop. C'est un peu tiré par les cheveux, mais bon!

Comment: Futé..........!

Answer (score -1):

Il s'agit probablement d'une confusion avec le terme "[bonhomme de neige](https://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/bonhomme_de_neige)".

Comment: Ceci semble peu probable vu la définition donnée par le TLF que cite la question : « Établissement où l'on accueille certaines catégories de personnes. Home d'enfants, home d'accueil pour les personnes âgées, home de neige  ». Confondre un établissement avec un bonhomme de neige ? J'en doute.

Comment: Mais "home" n'est pas français. Le fait que des auteurs mettent des mots anglais dans des phrases en français n'en fait pas des phrases en français pour autant. Ou alors, well.. Anything goes :)

Comment: Votre commentaire témoigne d'une méconnaissance de l'emprunt, de sa fréquence, et de sa dynamique... Bienvenue ! On estimerait que [5% des mots](https://fr.wiktionary.org/wiki/Annexe:Mots_fran%C3%A7ais_d%E2%80%99origine_anglaise) sont des emprunts à la langue anglaise. À l'[_Académie française_](http://www.academie-francaise.fr/questions-de-langue#12_strong-em-anglicismes-et-autres-emprunts-em-strong), on parle de l'emprunt, on donne des chiffres selon les époques etc. Voir aussi la [BDL](http://bdl.oqlf.gouv.qc.ca/bdl/gabarit_bdl.asp?T1=emprunt&T3.x=0&T3.y=0). Ce n'est pas _anything goes_.

Comment: Possiblement un emploi à la page à une époque. Intéressant aussi parce que c'est un cas où on utilise le mot anglais avec p.-ê. une idée de _standing_, la pointe de snobisme, un effet au registre, comme à mon avis quand en anglais on emploie le français (on dit pour un effet recherché ou le registre soutenu, _elevated_) et non parce qu'on ne connaît pas le mot en français etc. De plus je me dis qu'en Belgique l'anglais est peut-être plus connu et utilisé dans certains contextes, mais ici au final c'est vraiment une curiosité au lexique historique vu qu'on a pas l'air de connaître. Merci.

Comment: @user3177: Tous ces mots empruntés à la langue anglaise, un jour, il faudra bien les lui rendre.

Comment: Une recherche sur Google pointe essentiellement vers des sites de définitions de mots-croisés ("igloo", "chalet"), genre enclin à faire de l'esprit pour dérouter le joueur. Il n'est donc pas impossible que l'exemple cité provienne de là et soit une sorte de calembour sur "homme des neiges".

Answer (score -3):

L'usage du mot "home" en Français, comme vous l'avez noté, n'a pas survécu. On ne l'utilise aujourd'hui plus du tout.

Concernant l'expression "home de neige", sans plus d'information sur l'endroit où vous l'avez trouvée et la date de l'ouvrage il est impossible d'y répondre avec certitude.

Néanmoins ma supposition est qu'il s'agit d'une erreur, et que l'expression aurait du être "homme de neige" (man of snow).

Comment: Le PO dit explicitement dans la question où il / elle a lu « home de neige » Vu la définition donnée par le TLF il  semble tout à fait improbable qu'il s'agisse d'une erreur sur (bon)homme de neige. Confondre un établissement avec un bonhomme de neige ? J'en doute.

Comment: La définition donnée dans le TLF est  soit tirée de, soit reprise par, le [*Dictionnaire Etymologique des Anglicismes et des Américanismes*](https://books.google.fr/books?id=b2pjAgAAQBAJ&pg=PA616&lpg=PA616&dq=%22home+de+neige%22&source=bl&ots=b4eIs1q8Wv&sig=70CwHg2ndnjl-yS4tUY3CvvbGuE&hl=fr&sa=X&ved=0ahUKEwivo5D8qL3UAhVLJVAKHQ8XDPcQ6AEIWDAM#v=onepage&q=%22home%20de%20neige%22&f=false)  Jean-Paul Kurtz, 2014.